# Why is this inequality involving distance metrics true?

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to see why this is true  -- here $d$ is a distance metric:
$$ \
\left| \inf_{y\in X} (d(x,y)-g(y)) - \inf_{y\in X} (d(x',y)-g(y)) \right| \leq \sup_{y\in X} \left| d(x,y)-d(x',y)\right|
$$

I just don't see how this is true since we may have different optimal $y$'s for $d(x,y)-g(y)$ and $d(x',y)-g(y)$. Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume here that the two infima are finite.)

Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
By definition of $\inf$, there exists $y'\in X$ such that
$$
\inf_{y\in X} [d(x',y) - g(y)] \geq d(x', y') - g(y')-\varepsilon,
$$
hence
$$
\begin{split}
\inf_{y\in X} [d(x,y) - g(y)] -\inf_{y\in X} [d(x',y) - g(y)] 
& \leq d(x,y') - g(y') - [d(x', y') - g(y') - \varepsilon]
\\ & = d(x,y') - d(x',y') + \varepsilon 
\\ & \leq \sup_{y\in X} |d(x,y) - d(x',y)| + \varepsilon.
\end{split}
$$
Similarly, we can prove the symmetric inequality
$$
\inf_{y\in X} [d(x',y) - g(y)] -\inf_{y\in X} [d(x,y) - g(y)]
\leq
 \sup_{y\in X} |d(x,y) - d(x',y)| + \varepsilon.
$$
Hence,
$$
\left|
\inf_{y\in X} [d(x,y) - g(y)] -\inf_{y\in X} [d(x',y) - g(y)] 
\right|
\leq
\sup_{y\in X} |d(x,y) - d(x',y)| + \varepsilon.
$$